# C# duda básica para evitar el crasheo

Tags: c#

el caso es que estoy empezando a estudiar programación, y en clase, mientas avanzamos temario vamos en paralelo haciendo un juego así cutre.
La duda que tengo es, como puedo hacer para con el código este, que si el usuario añade una letra o nada, no crashee.
Gracas.
[image: Maze]

Comment: Por favor mira [ask]. Tambien no pegues una imagen de tu codigo, pega tu codigo, porque si alguien quiere problarlo, con la imagen no podra copiarlo y probarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que pides, puedes utilizar un switch:

```
Switch(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())){
    Case 1:
         //Lo que necesitas para el caso 1, que es "New game"
         break;//Rompe o "sale" del caso 1
    Case 2:
         //Lo que necesitas para el caso dos, que es "Load game"
         break;
   //sigue esa secuencia por cada caso que necesites
   default://en caso de que no se cumpla todo lo anterior, lo que hará por defecto
         //Instrucciones que hará cuando el "case" no pueda acceder a ninguno de los anteriores
   break;
}
```

Esta estructura es como un conjunto de `if`, que yo utilizaba en programas de ese estilo, igual, y si quieres investigar acerca del `try/catch`, podría serte útil.
Te dejo un enlace con documentación acerca del [Switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/06tc147t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Desgraciadamente este codigo le va a tirar error si lo que se ingresa no es un numero. :(

Comment: acabo de leer esto, no tomé en cuenta eso, pero bueno, ví tu respuesta, así que no le moveré nada a esta,+1 para ti hermano

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Victor, tu codigo tira un error porque recibes por consola un string (siempre se recibe eso por consola), pero inmediatamente tratas de convertirlo a entero, cuando no siempre eso es posible, sobre todo si no recibes un numero.

La mejor solucion es una mezcla entre lo que te dice Ronquillo y Victor.

Victor utiliza directamente una comparacion entre strings, que a vos te sirve para no tener que hacer una transformacion y te evita usar un `try catch` o un `int.TryParse`.

```
bool siguejugano=true;
While (siguejugando)
{
  Switch(Console.ReadLine()){
    Case "1":
      //Lo que necesitas para el caso 1, que es "New game"
      break;//Rompe o "sale" del caso 1
    Case "2":
      //Lo que necesitas para el caso dos, que es "Load game"
      break;
    Case "0":
      siguejugando=false;
      break;
    default://en caso de que no se cumpla todo lo anterior, lo que hará por defecto
      break;
  }
}
```

La variable `bool siguejugando` se usa para controlar si en algun momento selecciona un 0 y asi deja de mostrar el menu.

Answer (score 0):

La razón es que estás intentando convertir a entero lo que se introduce por consola, y bien, o el dato introducido es correcto o generará una excepción. Tienes dos opciones:

1. Controlar la excepción mediante sentencias ***try catch***  (cosa que si eres novato no te aconsejo).
2. Declara la variable *option* como tipo *String*. La sentencia `Console.ReadLine();` devuelve un objeto de tipo *String*. Podrías utilizar el método *Equals* de *String* para comparar si dos valores son iguales pero sin tener problemas de conversión. Ej:

   ```
   String option = Console.ReadLine();

   while(!option.Equals("0")){  // Mientras la opción no sea 0

       if (option.Equals("1") || option.Equals("2")|| option.Equals("3") || option.Equals("4")||option.Equals("5")){

          // La opcion está entre el 1 y el 5 ambos incluidos
       }else{

         //Opción no conocida
       }

   option=Console.ReadLine(); //Vuelve a leer una nueva entrada de datos
   }
   // Fin del programa
   ```